# Spotify web api returns status 500 on get playlists request

Tags: spotify

I consistently get this response

> { error: { status: 500, message: 'Server error.' } }

when I try to retrieve all playlists for my user using this endpoint

> GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlist

I am doing this repeatedly as a test case while I develop the plumbing for my Spotify web api application.

Sometimes it fails when I start at offset 0.  Sometimes it succeeds at offset 0 (and offset 50, 100, 150, etc.) and fails later.  I have about 900 playlists.

It fails whether I get 20 playlists at a time or the maximum of 50.

I see nothing unusual in the response headers.

Is this a bug on the Spotify's end?  I assume since I'm getting status 500 that this is not related to hitting a request rate limit of some kind, or some error in my request.

I would appreciate any insight anyone has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

Responses with status code 500 from the `/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists/` endpoint can be caused by a number of reasons, none of which is your application's fault. There are cases where a user's list of playlists (or an individual playlist) cause temporary issues in Spotify's backend. This occurs more often if the list of playlists have a lot of revisions, e.g. the user has an unusually large amount of playlists and have removed, added and moved them around a lot. We're working on resolving this but meanwhile we ask you to try again.

This isn't related to any of the query parameters sent in the request, it's simply an intermittent error.

> Is this a bug on the Spotify's end? I assume since I'm getting status 500 that this is not related to hitting a request rate limit of some kind, or some error in my request.

Spotify's Web API return a response with status code 429 if the request has been rate limited. A list of which status codes are returned from the Web API can be found in the [User Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#response-status-codes).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Does this problem impact other web api endpoints as well?

Comment: Since it's intermittent, I recommend retrying a couple of seconds later if possible. If it still doesn't work, I'd simply display an error to the user.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That's fine, but the list playlists API pretty much NEVER works with this user, no matter how many times I retry.  So I guess I can't have that functionality in my app.  :-(  Maybe I'll try to list playlists with limit=1 to see if I can isolate which playlist is causing the problem, and then skip it.  the {userid}/playlists/{playlistid}tracks API does seem to work more reliably.

Comment: Oh not at all!  Thanks. Is there some way to do so privately?

Comment: By the way I tried this with limit=1 a couple of times and it failed in different places. The first time it failed after about 150. The second after about 650. So it doesn't seem to be associated consistently with the same play list.

Comment: Email sent.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Michael, my account also returns error 500 when using the get playlists function. I run www.britify.com that was featured in Spotify's press release for it's US launch, has been featured by The Guardian, Time, on BBC Click (TV) and other sites. It currently runs on libspotify but I was asked by Spotify support to rewrite it using the web APIs, but they error on my account. Is there a private way I can send you my username?